# Why is my content showing up below other blocks?

Tags: theming

I did some work on my site and now i realize that even though my main page content block is weighted to be at the top, it shows below everything else within that area.

Is there any way someone can take a look and help me figure out why this is happening?

Using
- drupal 7
- omega3 main theme with a custom subtheme

example of my issue: http://www.destinationsound.net/contact

The two blocks "Buy Beats Front Page" and "Banner Ad Top" blocks are the two located above the contact form on the contact page (and other pages)
[image]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your block configuration page with us?

Comment: image added of the content region. Let me know if you would like to see all regions. (there's alot)

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the row weights and dragging the items around. Change them any way you want - then save configuration then go back in and change them to the way you want them to be and save again. Dont forget to clear your caches.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have dont both dragging and weights and vice versa. Also, I have cleared my cache and still no change.  Is it possible that a .tpl.php file is causing this? I realize that there are lots of those files when working with Omega3.

Comment: Anytime I have had this issue the above helped me. I havent worked with Omega3 so I cant comment on whether that could be the problem. sorry